# angularjs very slow fetching ng-repeat data from a json file

Tags: angularjs, getjson, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a json file which has about 8000 contacts in it, fetching all that data takes a very long time with angularjs using ng-repeat, is there any fix for this?

Comment: You must think of pagination for that kind of big data. Although fetching json faster and optimizing ng-repeat are different things, paging can work for both.

Comment: yes,only put in the ng-repeat the data your are going to display.nothing more.just dont throw jsons at it.

Comment: Have you tried to gzip your json response, most of the browsers support gzip compression. This way you can fetch the json quick. Then displaying it is a matter of you skill in javascript.

Comment: i also need to search the data through search field, will it be fast enough to bring in the data i search for

Comment: I have this problem, but I'm only fetching 6 records at a time. It takes ~1 second, which on an AJAX app is very noticeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot expect much speed when retrieving such large records. You can optimize the ng-repeat performance by using

1. Track by
2. [BindOnce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce)
3. [Infinite Scroll](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)

These things will improve the performance to an extent.