# Working with large json files in AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

Ok so the problem is that the webapp gets really slow when loading the json data om mobile (iPhone 5s)
There is no backend involved.. just static files..

The current json file contains about 4800+ objects..

I use "limitTo" set to 20 but I guess that the performance problem is related to the binding on all elements?

Also I need to be able to filter from the full list and not just the 20 that are currently displaying..

Any Ideas on how to do this?

Edit: Created a plunker for it as well, http://embed.plnkr.co/jHhAKdD9z91OCusfptTd/

Comment: Maybe this related issue can help:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261331/angularjs-very-slow-fetching-ng-repeat-data-from-a-json-file)

Ng-repeat is a realy big performance issue.

Try to show just the data, that the user really can see, so if he swipes, reload and display.
If you search, maybe rather "reload" the complete ng-repeat after search is completed instead of an "instant result".

Comment: Would it make sense to cache the objects some how? Perhaps using http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/ ?

Comment: I don't think that would help you, I mean, the ng-repeat still need to run over the data object and display the data at all.

You could execute the $http.get on your application load with an timeout, to do it async.

Also could try to set your JSON-Data into a variable (static) and not load it, and have a look if you're getting a better performance?

Comment: Some related links: http://josh.zeigler.us/technology/web-development/how-big-is-too-big-for-json/ , https://stackify.com/top-11-json-performance-usage-tips/